# Rotated text overlays sticky navigation bar

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, sticky

I'm building a website which has a sticky navigation bar, and a table.
The first column of the table contains vertical text. The table is long enough so it can be scrolled. However, when scrolled, the rotated text behaves in a funny way: it appears over the navigation bar. All the other text behaves as expected.

Here is my example.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>Funny overlay example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <div>
                Sticky Navbar
            </div>
        </nav>
        <section>
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr><td rowspan="8" class="cell_vert_text"><div class="rotwrap"><div class="textcon">Problematic Text</div></div></td><td class="cell_horiz_text">Ok Text</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="cell_horiz_text">Ok Text</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="cell_horiz_text">Ok Text</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="cell_horiz_text">Ok Text</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="cell_horiz_text">Ok Text</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="cell_horiz_text">Ok Text</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="cell_horiz_text">Ok Text</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="cell_horiz_text">Ok Text</td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the style.css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
    background: #ff0000;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

table td.cell_vert_text {
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 1.5em;
}

table td.cell_vert_text div.rotwrap div.textcon {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    margin-left: -10em;
    margin-right: -10em;
}
```

I suspect that the rotation has some sideeffects on the DOM structure, but I don't really understand what's happening. I tried to solve the problem by introducing z-index attributes, but it did not help.
I'm not only looking for a solution to push the rotated text behind the navbar, but a clear explanation of what is really happening. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform on an element creates a [stacking context](https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/), since none of it's parent is a stacking context, it's on the same level of the other stacking context, the navbar (position sticky).

When we have 2 stacking contexts on the same level, and both without `z-index`, the last one is shown on top of those that come before it.

The solution: Set z-index on the navbar:

```
.navbar {
  z-index: 1;
  background: #ff0000;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Demo**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar {
  z-index: 1;
  background: #ff0000;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

table td.cell_vert_text {
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 1.5em;
}

table td.cell_vert_text div.rotwrap div.textcon {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  margin-left: -10em;
  margin-right: -10em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div>
      Sticky Navbar
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section>
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="8" class="cell_vert_text">
            <div class="rotwrap">
              <div class="textcon">Problematic Text</div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="cell_horiz_text">Ok Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="cell_horiz_text">Ok Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="cell_horiz_text">Ok Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="cell_horiz_text">Ok Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="cell_horiz_text">Ok Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="cell_horiz_text">Ok Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="cell_horiz_text">Ok Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="cell_horiz_text">Ok Text</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  height: 5000px;
}
.navbar {
    background: #ff0000;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

table td.cell_vert_text {
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 1.5em;
}

table td.cell_vert_text div.rotwrap div.textcon {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    margin-left: -10em;
    margin-right: -10em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div>
      Sticky Navbar
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section>
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr><td rowspan="8" class="cell_vert_text"><div class="rotwrap"><div class="textcon">Problematic Text</div></div></td><td class="cell_horiz_text">Ok Text</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="cell_horiz_text">Ok Text</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="cell_horiz_text">Ok Text</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="cell_horiz_text">Ok Text</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="cell_horiz_text">Ok Text</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="cell_horiz_text">Ok Text</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="cell_horiz_text">Ok Text</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="cell_horiz_text">Ok Text</td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Give the navbar rule a positive `z-index` value

```
.navbar {
 background: #ff0000;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately I cannot mark both answers accepted, and I'll go with the other identical one, which was posted just a few seconds earlier.